# expiryDate in craft_templatecaches

Tags: cache, datetime, timezone

I've found this in the [documenation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/date-time-fields):

> Dates and times are both formatted for the user’s preferred locale.
>   They are displayed in the site’s timezone, however they get stored in
>   UTC like all other dates in Craft.

That's fine.

I use this timezone: UTC+1 (CET) - Europe/Rome

As expected everything is saved in the database with an UTC offset of minus one hour exept the expiryDate in the craft_templatecaches table: the UTC offset is minus two hours.

Here is my code snippet:

```
{% set expiredNews = craft.entries.section('news').order('expiryDate')|first %}
{% set expiryDate = expiredNews.expiryDate %}

{% cache until expiryDate %}
```

**Example:**

expiryDate in entry: 2015-04-01 00:00:00

expiryDate in cache: 2015-03-31 22:00:00

Why is there an offset of two hours and what does that mean for cache invalidation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code example works.

Short and simple answer: **daylight saving time (DST)**

Standard time: -1 hour in database

Daylight saving time: -2 hours in database

Comment: That's a workaround, no solution. Is it?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this locally. Using UTC+1 and the original template code and getting the proper `2015-03-26 10:00:00` in both `craft_templatecaches` and `craft_entries->expiryDate` column.

Comment: Oh my goodness, now I know why: **daylight saving time**

Comment: Haha... it's always something. :)